# Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available

Tags: android, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-java-client

I'm working on an android app that interfaces with a google sheet. I was following the api documentation for writing values to certain cells but I'm getting this error here:

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available.`

I have made sure to set my credentials in google cloud platform for my project and downloaded the .json file to `src\main\resources` in my android studio project.

here is the code that is supposed to write the data:

```
package com.example.frcscout22

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.ValueRange
import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials
import java.util.*


class Data : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_data) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val spinner = view.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.defense_spinner)

        val aa = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, resources.getStringArray(R.array.Defenses))
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)

        spinner.adapter = aa

        view.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.defense_spinner).visibility = View.GONE
        view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView6).visibility = View.GONE
        view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Team_Defended).visibility = View.GONE
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_data, container, false)
        val checkBox = view.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox)

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                view.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.defense_spinner).visibility = View.VISIBLE
                view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView6).visibility = View.VISIBLE
                view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Team_Defended).visibility = View.VISIBLE

            } else {
                view.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.defense_spinner).visibility = View.GONE
                view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView6).visibility = View.GONE
                view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Team_Defended).visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }

        val clear = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
        clear.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Match_Number).setText("")
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Team_Number).setText("")
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Auto_Points).setText("")
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Teleop_Points).setText("")
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Endgame_Points).setText("")
            view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Team_Defended).setText("")
            view.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.defense_spinner).setSelection(0)
            view.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkBox).isChecked = false
        })

        val table : MutableList<MutableList<Any>> = mutableListOf(mutableListOf("test", "test2"))
        val values = ValueRange()
        values.majorDimension = "ROWS"
        values.setValues(table)
        val button = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            setRow("1fs1U9-LMmkmQbQ2Kn-rNVHIQwh6_frAbwaTp7MSyDIA", "Sheet1!A1:B1", values)
        })

        // Return the fragment view/layout
        return view
    }

    private fun setRow(spreadSheetID: String, range: String, values: ValueRange) {
        val credentials: GoogleCredentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault().createScoped(
            Collections.singleton(
                SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS))

        val requestInitializer: HttpRequestInitializer = HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials)

        val service: Sheets = Sheets.Builder(NetHttpTransport(), GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), requestInitializer).setApplicationName("FRCScout22").build()

        service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadSheetID, range, values)
            .setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED")
            .execute();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why I may be getting this error? Thanks!!

Comment: you should probably be following this example [Java Quick start](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java)

Answer (score 0):

[Application Default Credentials (ADC)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#automatically) is a process that looks for the credentials in various places including the env var `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDNTIALS`.

If `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDNTIALS` is unset ADC fails and raises an error.

Comment: How can I set the GOOGLE APPLICATION CREDENTIALS? would that be in the java quick start?

Comment: its an env var TBH its normally used with cloud apis I at a loss why you are seeing it with android.    I suggest looking at the quick start because I am wondering if you are using the wrong code